# Render partial inside a javascript variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I´m using Rails 3.2, and bootstrap 3.2 and trying to render a partial to be shown in a bootbox control, but no luck.

```
 bootbox.dialog({
      title: "New appointment",
      message: '<%= (render "form_remote") %>',
```

The problem is that it render the newlines, and breaks the script code. This is the generated code:

```
bootbox.dialog({
      title: "New appointment",
      message: '<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 ">
    <label class="" for="person_id">Nome</label>
    <div>
      <input class="form-control" id="person_id" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

',
```

To work for now, I rewrote my partial in a single line...

There are another way to do all this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have parenthesis around the render?  Does the js console give you any errors or indication of what is happening when you try the render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [escape_javascript](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript), e.g:

```
bootbox.dialog({
      title: "New appointment",
      message: '<%= escape_javascript(render "form_remote") %>',
```